# Calculating a limit with Harmonic number

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to prove that

$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{\sum^n_{k=1} \frac{1}{k}} { \ln(n) })^{ \ln(n) } = e^γ$
where $γ$ the Euler-Mascheroni constant. We know that that:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum^n_{k=1} \frac{1}{k}}{ \ln(n) } = 1$

By approximating the sum with integrals
$$
\ln(n+1)=\int_1^{n+1}\frac1x\mathrm dx\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\le 1+\int_1^n\frac1x\mathrm dx=1+\ln n
$$
since $1/k$ is decreasing for $k\ge 1$. We have that
$$
\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n}=\frac{\ln n+\ln(1+\frac1n)}{\ln n}\to1
$$
as $n\to\infty$ and we obtain the result. But I can't calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{\sum^n_{k=1} \frac{1}{k}} { \ln(n) })^{ \ln(n) } = e^γ.$ Any help?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is... Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Your estimates are a bit too course. Recall, $\gamma = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} H_n-\ln(n)$ and $e^x=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+x/n)^n$. So in this case,

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{H_n}{\ln(n)}\right)^{\ln(n)}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left( \frac{H_n-\ln(n)+\ln(n)}{\ln(n)} \right)^{\ln(n)}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{H_n-\ln(n)}{\ln(n)}\right)^{\ln(n)}.$$

Let $g_n:=H_n-\ln(n)$. Then the inside of the limit is equivalent to:

$$\exp[\ln(n)\ln(1+g_n/\ln(n))]=\exp[g_n+\ln(n)o(g_n/\ln(n))],$$

which gives the desired result since $g_n$ approaches a constant.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you transformed the last expression for the limit into the expression with the exponential? I'm not quite sure how you did that (though I'm aware of the limit definition of $e^x$). Would it be possible for you to provide a few additional steps? Thank you.

Comment: @OmicronGamma: $\ln(n)o(g_n/ln(n))\rightarrow 0$. Does that help?

Comment: I understand that part, but not how you transformed $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{g_n}{\ln n} \right) ^{\ln n}$$ into the exponential.

Comment: @OmicronGamma: $a^n=\exp(n\ln(a))$.

Answer (score 1):

We can write

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k =\log(n)+\gamma+O\left(\frac1n\right)\tag1$$

Dividing $(1)$ by $\log(n)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k}{\log(n)}\right)^{\log(n)}&=\underbrace{\left(1+\frac{\gamma}{\log(n)}\right)^{\log(n)}}_{\to \gamma}\underbrace{\left(1+\frac{O\left(\frac1{n}\right)}{\log(n)+\gamma}\right)^{\log(n)}}_{\to 1}
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Answer (score 1):

Want to show
$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{\sum^n_{k=1} \frac{1}{k}} { \ln(n) })^{ \ln(n) } = e^γ
$.

Let
$f(n)
=(\frac{\sum^n_{k=1} \frac{1}{k}} { \ln(n) })^{ \ln(n) }
$.

$\begin{array}\\
g(n)
&=\ln(f(n))\\
&=\ln(n)(\ln(\sum^n_{k=1} \frac{1}{k})-\ln(\ln(n)))\\
&=\ln(n)(\ln(\ln(n)+\gamma+O(1/n))-\ln(\ln(n)))\\
&=\ln(n)(\ln\ln(n)+\ln(1+\gamma/\ln(n)+O(1/(n\ln(n)))-\ln(\ln(n)))\\
&=\ln(n)(\ln(1+\gamma/\ln(n)+O(1/(n\ln(n))))\\
&=\ln(n)(\gamma/\ln(n)+O(1/(\ln^2(n))))\\
&=\gamma+O(1/(\ln(n))))\\
&\to \gamma\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: How do you go from $ln(1 + \gamma /\ln (n) + O(1 /(n\ln (n)))$ to $\gamma/\ln (n) + O(1/\ln^2 (n))$? Could you please elaborate on that step? Thank you.